# FMCW radar IQ data constellation

Tags: discrete-signals, radar, doppler

I am trying to replicate the basic method of vital signal detection based on FMCW radars I found in classical literature on the subject. The issue I am facing at the moment is that of IQ data DC offset correction. As shown in the two figures below, the IQ data in an overwhelming majority of papers at the selected range bin of interest appear to be "circular" which is just not the case for me with echo data from Texas Instrument's IWR1843BOOST Evaluation Module.
[image][image]

In contrast, the IQ data I obtain from the range bin at which my target is located looks like this;
[image]

Not remotely close to anything I have seen in most papers so far. So my question is, what could be the reason for the huge discrepancy I'm observing.
Thanks